# can't install weblogic on docker on OracleLinuxServer 6.7

Tags: linux, curl, linux-kernel, docker

I am trying to install Weblogic on docker following instructions on the site
[Getting Started with Oracle WebLogic Server on Docker Containers](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/getting_started_with_oracle_weblogic)
on VirtualBox with Oracle Linux Server 6.7 and kernel `3.8.13-118.2.1.el6uek.x86_64`.
I have done correctly till step 4 and when I ran step 5 i.e.

```
sudo sh buildDockerImage.sh -d
```

first it installs OracleLinux then after some time it shows me error like:

```
https://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/UEKR3/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml          
:[Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to public-yum.oracle.com:80; No route to host"  
Trying other mirror
```

I followed proxy settings on Docker, Git and on my Linux machine as well.

What should I do to install Weblogic on Docker?

Comment: I am using this virtual linux "Oracle VM Templates for Oracle Linux" OVM_OL6U7_x86_64_PVM on one machine and simple linux OS on other. On both machine I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you connect to public-yum.oracle.com via your host, i.e. outside of Docker? What happens if you run

```
# yum update
```

On the host? It should be configured to use public-yum.oracle.com as well, so if that works, Docker should work too.

If that doesn't work, your issue isn't with Docker, but with networking or DNS resolution from the host itself.

Comment: @Bruno Borges , How should i resolve this issue then?

Comment: @verma_neeraj, no idea... as Djelibeybi said, this doesn't seem to be an Oracle Linux issue, and it's definitely not a WebLogic (on Docker) issue. Make sure you have your network settings ok.

Comment: @Bruno Borges, I went to your blog [WebLogic on Docker Containers Series, Part 1](https://blogs.oracle.com/brunoborges/entry/docker_and_weblogic_enabling_cloud) and installed as per instructions and now its working. Thanks a lot.